# In quantmod, function findValleys() return error value

Tags: r, quantmod

In quantmod, below code `findValleys(mt)` return value `5`,but I think it should be `4` (cause 0.1 is the min value).Anyone can help on this ? Thanks!

```
 library(quantmod)
    mt <- c(1,2,3,0.1,4,9,8)
    findValleys(mt)
```

Comment: I think 5 is correct, as it returns the first period after the valley has been detected. Under `?findValleys` it says: "...the function can only define it after a change in direction has occurred. This means that the function will always return the first period after the peak/valley of the data, so as not to accidentally induce a look-ahead bias."

Comment: Got it,Thanks for your words!